# Left Outer Join and Union

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have two tables that have a parent and associated via a foreign key through their parent table, i.e.

```
TableP
 -----------------
| C1  | P2  | P3  |
 -----------------
   0    P2    P3

TableA
 -----------------
| C1  | A2  | A3  |
 -----------------
   0    A21   A31
   0    A22   A32

TableB
 -----------------
| C1  | B2  | B3  |
 -----------------
   0    B21   B31
   0    B22   B32
```

What I need is to pull the data in the following result set:

```
 ---------------------------------
| C1  |  A2  |  A3  |  B2  |  B3  |
 ---------------------------------
   0     A21   A31    NULL   NULL
   0     A22   A32    NULL   NULL
   0    NULL   NULL    B21    B31
   0    NULL   NULL    B22    B32
```

Is this possible through a combination of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `UNION`?

**UPDATE**:

Since one of the commenters answered the question but not in the form of an answer, here is the solution that worked for me:

```
SELECT p.c1, a.a2 a2, a.a3 a3, NULL b2, NULL b3 
FROM tablep p LEFT OUTER JOIN tablea a on a.c1 = p.c1 
UNION 
SELECT p.c1, NULL a2, NULL a3, b.b2 b2, b.b3 b3 
FROM tablep p LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb b on b.c1 = p.c1;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this only using LEFT OUTER JOIN and UNION???

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN - fetches data only if present in the left table.

Comment: Why does `tableP` appear in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT P.C1,A.A2,A.A3,B.B2,B.B3 FROM TableP P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A ON P.C1 = A.C1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON P.C1 = B.C1
```

Have used Left Outer Join, as you asked for, no need of Union

Comment: Like Backtrack's answer, it returns a Cartesian product.

Comment: You can see the result set in the [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34fab3/1). And I think Backtrack, or someone else, removed his answer for some reason.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, Malvon, the left outer join the three tables return a cartesian product for tableb and tablec. Is there any reason to not use left outer join and union the two result set together? for example, select p.c1, a.a2, a.a3, null, null from tablep p left outer join tablea a on a.c1=p.c1 union select p.c1, null, null, b.b2, b.b3 from tablep p left outer join tableb b on b.c1=p.c1;

Comment: @ivenxu Actually, your solution works with some minor modifications. Thank you. SELECT p.c1, a.a2 a2, a.a3 a3, NULL b2, NULL b3 from tablep p LEFT OUTER JOIN tablea a on a.c1 = p.c1 UNION SELECT p.c1, NULL a2, NULL a3, b.b2 b2, b.b3 b3 FROM tablep p LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb b on b.c1 = p.c1; Would you like to provide this in an answer format to get credits?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested), make changes if there are some syntax errors.

```
select coalesce(taba.p1,tabb.p1), taba.a2, taba.a3, tabB.b2, tabB.b3
  from (select 'A'||to_char(rownum) RR, a2, a3, tablep.p1 p1
          from tablea JOIN TABLEP ON (tablea.p1 = tablep.p1)) taba
     FULL OUTER JOIN  
       (select 'B'||to_char(rownum) RR, b2, b3, tablep.p1 p1
          from tableb JOIN TABLEP ON (tableb.p1 = tablep.p1)) tabB
    on (taba.rr = tabB.rr and tabB.p1 = tabA.p1);
```

Comment: this almost works except that the `taba.p1` is only correct for the result set from `tablea` but are `NULL' for the rest (`tableb` rows).

Comment: For that, I would consider using coalesce, modified the post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TableA.A2` is always not equal to `TableB.B2`

```
SELECT  tableP.C1,tableA.A2,tableA.A3,tableB.B2,tableB.B3
FROM tableA,tableB,tableP
WHERE tableP.C1 = tableA.C1
  AND tableP.C1 = tableB.C1
  And tableA.A2 = tableB.B2(+)
UNION ALL
SELECT  tableP.C1,tableA.A2,tableA.A3,tableB.B2,tableB.B3
FROM tableA,tableB,tableP
WHERE tableP.C1 = tableA.C1
  AND tableP.C1 = tableB.C1
  And tableB.B2 = tableA.A2(+)
```